# convert asterisk to value in excel cell

Tags: excel-formula

I receive data from my client and some of the fields are with the combination of asterisk (*) and letter. It is intentional and they don't want to provide the full information. Is there anyway we can convert asterisk in excel to correct value.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks, B

Comment: Can you give an example please, and let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's in the alpha numerical form for the Items. For example: ABCD234567 will receive as ABCD23****.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your client is obfuscating information in the data they are submitting to you likely due to some privacy or security concerns. This isn't a clever algorithm that stores the values and just changes the display. This is actually how the values are stored in excel (ie "Ni***las").

If this is the case, the short answer is NO you cannot convert the asterisk to the intended information because that information is simply not stored in the excel document.

You could probably create some clever heuristics that could tickle the info from a library of common terms relating to the data (ie "Ni***las" ~ "Nicholas"). But this would have a huge overhead (creating and maintaining) and would be strive with false positives. And depends entirely on the data being somewhat predictable. If you are trying to get the entire number from a masked Credit Card for example then as each item is unique it would be impossible to determine the missing elements of your data (Ceteris paribus).

Please let me know if I have misinterpreted your question.